# openvpn client - dynamic server/proxy ip

Tags: scripting, openvpn

We're running an openvpn server and let some clients connect to the vpn server through a socks proxy. This already works.

Our problem is now, that we need to change the ip address of our proxy frequently (once every 2 - 3 days) and can't deliver the ip address via dynamic DNS. We can still fetch an ip address on linux with wget for example and that's what I'd like to do automatically because there are too many clients to update them manually every time.

I've read that there is a `--client-connect` directive that runs a script before it connects. IIRC, the proxy ip has to be written in the config file and would already be read when the client-connect script is run.

**How do I update my proxy ip each time a connection is opened? Preferably without third party tools (portable binaries or scripts are ok).**

(I need a solution for windows, linux and mac but I'm okay with one solution for each platform.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mechanism within OpenVPN to do this. The `client-connect` script is run on the server side so it isn't useful. Your only non-DNS approach is to write a script which rebuilds the OpenVPN configuration every time. But rather get DNS working.

Comment: That's too bad. It isn't in our hands to get the DNS working. China's blocking us ;). Anyway, thanks for your information.